# Creating XPath for a label with half bold font

Tags: vb.net, selenium, xpath

I am coding in selenium and vb.net and am quite naive to it. I have a question label that is half bold and half not. The part that is not bold is exactly same as a previous question on the same page and so are the all the other properties.

Hence, to create the xpath, I have to use the text (half bold and half not.)  Firebug shows the element as:

```
<label class="control-label ng-binding" ng-bind-html="renderHtml(question.definition.text)">
Do you have any
<b>existing Critical Illness cover</b>
?
</label>
```

I tried writing the xpath as follows:

```
//label[contains(text(),'Do you have any existing Critical Illness cover')]
```

This did not work.  I also tried this, unsuccessfully:

```
.//strong[contains(text(),'existing Critical Illness cover')]
```

Is there a way to pick up that element?

Comment: show `HTML` for this label

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select the label element which has text containing 'Do you have any' which also has a child element  that has text containing 'Critical Illness Cover':

```
//label[contains(text(),'Do you have any') and ./b[contains(text(),'existing Critical Illness cover')]]
```

Comment: guess it was the extra spaces that created the issue. But the contains worked. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
//label[normalize-space(text())="Do you have any"]/b[text()="existing Critical Illness cover"]
```

Comment: it was the extra spaces that i did not realise had created the issue. contains worked. So i guess normalize space would work too. Thank you very much!